# Do we need to compile JAR for JDK upgrade?

Tags: java

For our java project, we use several JAR libraries. Some of the source code for the JAR libraries have been lost.

We will be upgrading the JRE version soon, do you know if we need to recompile the JAR libraries for the new JRE version? Since we don't have the source, is there a 100% accurate decompiler?

Comment: Hum, java always keep backwards compatibility, so you don't need to recompile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, all JDK versions are backwards-compatible with respect to older jars.

You do not need to recompile.

The only exception to this is if the JAR implements (not uses, but implements) a JDBC driver.

Comment: +1 If you only use the subset of methods you implemented, it may not matter that a newer JDBC interface has more methods. e.g. if add method which are unused to an interface without re-compiling the implementation it can all work.

Comment: So what happens when the new JRE version has something depecrated...that would be removed in the upcoming JRE versions. Are you sure you don't have to recompile the JRE for the new version?

Comment: Nothing marked as deprecated has *ever* been removed. You do not have ever to recompile in any circumstance you're likely to run into.

Comment: Thats only true on paper. I remember at least *two* instances where code stopped working (there was something changed with JFrame's ContentPane form 1.3 to 1.4 and recently there was quite an ugly change in System.execute()'s behaviour that probably broke quite a few tools).

Comment: @Durandal "Backwards compatible" does not mean "fails to fix bugs in previous implementation"

Comment: @kittylyst What "Backwards compatible" really means is ambigous, unless the JRE somewhere explicitly defines the meaning of the term (not that I'm aware it does anywhere). Class-signature compatible and functional compatibility are both valid interpretations IMO. And since the question is essentially aimed at "will our code run unchanged" I think the asker should be aware that there can be issues with functionality. It may, it may not. No guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to re-compile a Java 1.0 JAR on a Java 8 JVM.

What you could have is a bug in your code which doesn't show up in your version but does show up in a never version. e.g. you depended on some undefined behaviour or a bug which was later fixed.  In this case, you would have to fix your code, re-compiling it wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Java is backward compatible, so you can use the jars compiled with an older jdk running with the latest jre versions. But if you are using some jdk specific classes, which have changed in the latest version, then only you may encounter problem. The probability of this is very less i believe.

Answer (score 0):

There are some *internal* classes, like Sun's Base64 encoding/decoding, that will slowly disappear in newer versions. You may run against OpenJDK to check whether there are problems with sun packages.